# ScrollBar Size Unusual Behavior in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a navigation controller, that programmatically loads several views. In one view I display list of documents that users can scroll through icons. When the device is put on its side (landscape). I am using a UIScrollView I get this weird shadow when scrolling. Does anyone have any idea on what I can check to see what is causing this shadow. Upon closure inspection I found that its not really a shadow, but it is the scroll bar that has been increased in size. I also found this occurs when I am in my second view only after going to another view, so when you click a button it loads a third view, when I go back using the navigation controller, I get the problem.

```
[scrv removeFromSuperview];
scrv = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
[scrv setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrv setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++){
     //removed for simplicity
     //loads several subviews
    }
}
[self setVisual];
[self.view addSubview:scrv];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something to layout the scroll view's subviews?  I had a similar problem because I was laying out the scroll view's subviews linearly, and had forgotten that the indicators are themselves subviews of the scroll view.